# Cómo evitar que un div pueda ser movido (drag and drop) en una zona del documento con jquery UI draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, jquery-ui

Estoy usando la función draggable de Jquery UI en varias divs y queria saber cómo puedo hacer para evitar que al mover un div y tratar de soltarlo fuera de su div padre(el div contenedor), en un espacio hotizontal.
 Es para evitar que este div no pueda estar posicionado en cierto espacio de la web:
este es mi codigo:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".caja1").draggable();
 $(".caja1").resizable();
    
    });
```

```css
      div.container
    {
      position: relative;
      border:1px solid black;
      padding-left: 10px;
    } 
div.caja1 {
width: 100px;
       height: 100px;
       position: relative;
     }
     
     div.caja1 {
       background: rgb(83, 53, 117)
     }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

   <div class="container">
    
    <div class="caja1" contenteditable="true">
       caja 1
      </div>

     <div class="caja1" contenteditable="true">
       caja 2
     </div>

   </div>
```

Cómo podria lograr esto? Solo quiero saber cómo hacer para que uno o más divs, no traspasen a su div padre, no se salgan de ese div padre.

Answer (score 2):

En la [documentación de jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com) hay un [ejemplo de lo que vos buscas hacer](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement), como este hay varios más, es totalmente recomendable pegarles una mirada antes de usar la librería.

Llendo al caso específico, lo que tenes que hacer es darle uso a `containment` para definir cual será el elemento del dominio que contendrá a tu elemento `Draggable`

Por ejemplo:

```js
$( function() { 
    //Acá se puede ver, que utilizo ''containment'' para definir que estará siempre dentro de #contenedor
    $( "#solodentro" ).draggable({ containment: "#contenedor"});
    $( "#todo" ).draggable();
  } );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
 
  <style>  
  #contenedor
  {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: blue;    
  }
  
  .ejemplo
  {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 4px;
  }  
  </style>  
  
  <div id="contenedor">  
    <div class="ejemplo" id="solodentro"> ¡No puedo salir! </div>
    <div class="ejemplo" id="todo"> ¡Yo si puedo! </div>  
  </div> 
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Tienes toda la razón man, Muchas Gracias. Me ha servido mucho. He leído la documentación de  Jquery UI Draggable y he encontrado varias cosas sobre eso. Gracias